# System.Array Doesn't contain a Definition for Length

Tags: c#, console-application

I try to calculate the number of words in a sentence using a Windows console application. But I'm new to the array thing and don't really know what can I do with that code:

```
string sentence;
Console.WriteLine("Enter your sentence:");
sentence = Console.ReadLine();

string [] words = sentence.Split(' ');
Console.WriteLine(sentence.Lenght);   // .Lenght is where I get the error from
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You've spelled it incorrectly, it's `Length`.

Comment: Length is spelt as i typed it, not Lenght :)

Comment: You are calling `Length` on the string: `sentence` not on the array: `words`. It should be `Console.WriteLine(words.Length);`

Comment: Oh damn yeah I spelled that incorrectly :P Thanks :D:D

Comment: if you are using VS then you should use ctrl + space, might help you out in future.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(sentence.Length);

Comment: @croxy Anyway also the `sentence` should have that property, so the other problem is simply the typo of `Length`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That is true. Depending on the problem description I thought pointing this error out would maybe save OP from another error source :)

Answer (score 1):

In the *easiest case* (when word == any characters between spaces) you can implement something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your sentence:");

// try not declaring local variable prematurely, but exacly where you want them
string sentence = Console.ReadLine();

// StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries - what if user starts with space? 
// separate words with two spaces, e.g. "  This   is a test    input  " 
// we want 5, right? 
int count = sentence
  .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Length; // Please, notice spelling

Console.WriteLine(count);   

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Im really dumb to not make sure if I had any spelling mistakes before I post here.Now when you spell Length word correctly,It works.Sorry guys,but,thanks.